# Can only change one letter in input in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have a class in Reactjs that looks like this:

```
 class ViewLegos extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.store.getAllLegoParts();
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        Header: "Piece",
        accessor: "piece"
      },
      {
        Header: "Type",
        accessor: "type"
      }
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.store.legoParts.state === "pending" ? (
          <h3>No data to display!</h3>
        ) : (
          <ReactTable
            defaultPageSize={10}
            className="-striped -highlight"
            data={this.props.store.legoParts.value}
            columns={columns}
            SubComponent={row => {
              console.log(row);
              return (
                <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Type</th>
                      <th>Start Date</th>
                      <th>End Date</th>
                      <th>Change it up!</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr onClick={this.props.store.changeData(row.original)}>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          onChange={e => this.props.store.addLego("piece", e)}
                          name="piece"
                          value={row.original.piece}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          onChange={e =>
                            this.props.store.addLego("type", e.target.value)
                          }
                          placeholder={this.props.store.type}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <Datetime
                          date="date"
                          onChange={e =>
                            this.props.store.addLego("startDate", e)
                          }
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <Datetime
                          type="date"
                          onChange={e => this.props.store.addLego("endDate", e)}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <button
                          onClick={() =>
                            this.props.store.updatePiece(row.original)
                          }
                        >
                          Update
                        </button>
                        <button
                          onClick={() =>
                            this.props.store.deletePiece(
                              this.props.row.original.id
                            )
                          }
                        >
                          Delete
                        </button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </Table>
              );
            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The changeData function which is called when a row is clicked, is in a MobX store and looks like this:

```
changeData = action("change state", part => {
    this.piece = part.piece;
  });
```

And when the value is changed in the input field, this function is enabled in a Mobx store:

```
 addLego = action("addLego", (storeName, value) => {
    this[storeName] = value.target.value;
  });
```

I want to be able to update the value in the input field.  However at the moment I can only change one letter!  Every time I enter more letters that one letter just changes to the new letter.  Grateful for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `changeData` function straight away on render. Give a function to `onClick` instead:

```
<tr onClick={() => this.props.store.changeData(row.original)}>
```